# Retrieve max values from array in covid api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I am needing to get max values from an array. I want to get the country with the max confirmed, recovered, and deaths from this API https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/daily

Can I have an additional function within useEffect to get the max? Any direction here is greatly appreciated.

Here is what I have so far -

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

//axios will be used to make api calls

const url = 'https://covid19.mathdro.id/api';

const fetchDailyData = async () => {
    try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(`${url}/daily`);

        return data.map(({ confirmed, deaths, reportDate: date }) => ({
            confirmed: confirmed.total,
            deaths: deaths.total,
            date,
        }));
    } catch (error) {
        return error;
    }
};

const MaxData = ({ data: { confirmed, recovered, deaths }, country }) => {
    const [dailyData, setDailyData] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchMyAPI = async () => {
            const initialDailyData = await fetchDailyData();

            setDailyData(initialDailyData);
        };

        fetchMyAPI();
    }, []);
```

Comment: you can chain the find function after map;

Comment: The link you've provided gives us daily data for one country only.  If you are looking for a daily maximum of all countries, you would have to retrieve the data from all countries in the first place. If for some reason, you are looking for the maximum value of a property in an array of objects, try: `const maxValueOfconfirmed = Math.max(...initialDailyData.map(o => o.totalConfirmed), 0);`